# Whats wrong with the below program?Java wait/notify is not working

Tags: java, multithreading

While trying to run below program it is getting hanged after "In consume."

```
1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : 6 : 7 : 8 : 9 : 10 : object realsed
object .....realsed
in consume..
```

```
public class MyThreadNew {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj=new Object();
        boolean produce=true;
        Thread t1=new Thread(new P(obj,produce));
        Thread t2=new Thread(new C(obj,produce));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class P implements Runnable{
    public Object obj;
    public static boolean produce;

    public P(Object obj, boolean produce){
        this.obj=obj;
        P.produce=produce;
    }

    public void produce(){
        synchronized (obj) {
            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
                System.out.print(i+" : ");
            }
            C.produce=false;
            obj.notifyAll();
            System.out.println("object realsed");
        }

        System.out.println("object .....realsed");
    }

    public void run(){
        produce();
    }
}

class C implements Runnable{
    public Object obj;
    public static boolean produce;

    public C(Object obj, boolean produce){
        this.obj=obj;
        C.produce=produce;
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException{
        while(true){
            if(!C.produce){
                System.out.println("in consume..");
                synchronized (obj) {

                    obj.wait();
                    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
                        System.out.print("Consumed: "+i+" : ");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            consume();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

what is wrong with my program??

Answer (score 5):

If the thread with `P` starts first, you get

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + " : ");
}
C.produce = false;
```

Then, assume a thread context switch happens, and the thread with `C`, runs the un-`synchronized`

```
while (true) {
    if (!C.produce) {
        System.out.println("in consume..");
```

then blocks at the `synchronized`. The other thread begins again, calling `notifyAll()`, then leaves its `synchronized` block. The thread with `C` starts again and calls

```
obj.wait();
```

blocking the app since there's nothing left to `notify` it.

Even if `C` started first, it would not be able to proceede past the `if` and you'd get the same behavior.

(On a separate note, `produce` should be `volatile`.)